# Воспроизведение видео на сайте по расписанию

Tags: трансляция

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите как реализовать на сайте воспроизведение видео по расписанию? 
На сервере будет храниться видеофайл, который должен ежедневно воспроизводиться в одно и тоже время. 
Как быть с прокруткой видео до определённого момента? Например если видео началось в 17:00, а пользователь зашел на сайт в 17:20, тогда он должен смотреть видео начиная с 20-той минуты, как это реализовать средствами php и javascript?

В принципе как вариант это можно реализовать используя видео с ютуба youtube. com/embed/xFa2_PVMeDQ?start=30 
get параметр (start=) отвечает за воспроизведение видео с указанной секунды, тогда понадобится скрипт, который будет отсчитывать время с начала трансляции (с 17:00) и дописывать его в параметр (start=) и тогда если посетитель зайдет на сайт в 17:20 видео начнется именно с 20 минуты.

Comment: поищи тут, если владеешь  js, найдешь то, что тебе надо точно...  исчерпывающая информация https://andew.ru/ru/pages/page/html5-audio-video-js-media-demonstration